# signing input for spend funds locked by this script

Tags: segregated-witness, signature, transaction-input, signrawtransaction, spending

Please explain how to sign input for raw transaction with privet key corresponding to 1st or 2nd public key in this script

"asm": "OP_IF 1694275749 OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP 03cd18ace3a339fcd0039fd87d7a7a8377537cd9a9f2afa2a3e76f40e53112a535 OP_CHECKSIG OP_ELSE 1694277749 OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP 036bb176ed8fe2e38949a63ff964eed3c5e79fd88ac011cad1eecf22702ea65d23 OP_CHECKSIG OP_ENDIF"

hex 63051694275749b1752103cd18ace3a339fcd0039fd87d7a7a8377537cd9a9f2afa2a3e76f40e53112a535ac67051694277749b17521036bb176ed8fe2e38949a63ff964eed3c5e79fd88ac011cad1eecf22702ea65d23ac68

address were I locked some sats bc1qes2v6ts5ckxuz5mkwdeukcn62hkac05kf97gugc4jnu3kj3wg5as3nes34

txID 14290ef656c05f8e0c06b6d99a6ae72c77a8809b3a69dd5fb00f07ce9cee1637
vout 133

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What goes in to the message of a transaction signature?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37093/what-goes-in-to-the-message-of-a-transaction-signature)

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451214/how-to-sign-and-verify-signature-with-ecdsa-in-python